# Which tense to describe tests/surveys in an APA paper?

Tags: tenses

I use past tense to report the results, but not sure if past tense is appropriate when it comes to the description of the survey itself, example below:

"The General Health Questionnaire (GHQ-12) was used to evaluate the severity of general psychiatric morbidity.The total scores range from 0 to 12. The internal consistency of the GHQ-12 in the present study was .85. Questionnaires for health outcomes included two items, one is designed for collecting the information whether the participants had chronic diseases, it was ranked in 4 levels (1 = 0 -2 times, 2 = 3 - 5 times,  3 = 6-9 times, 4 = equal or greater than 10 times). "

Comment: Create some consistency. At the moment, you jump back and forth between past to present.

Comment: I've always seen the past tense

Answer (score 1):

Whether the past or the present Tense, consistency is important. The study has already been over and now the reported is prepared and presented. I believe the present perfect and simple present tenses will do.

> "The General Health Questionnaire (GHQ-12) has been used to evaluate
>   the severity of general psychiatric morbidity.The total scores range
>   from 0 to 12. The internal consistency of the GHQ-12 in the present
>   study is .85. Questionnaires for health outcomes include two items,
>   one is designed for collecting the information whether the
>   participants have chronic diseases, it is ranked in 4 levels (1 = 0 -2
>   times, 2 = 3 - 5 times, 3 = 6-9 times, 4 = equal or greater than 10
>   times). "